# How to create categories for products in ERD model?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, uml, erd

I have designed an ERD for a website I am about to build.

This website has 2 groups: the `USER` and the `COMPANY`. Different companies (or shops, to be precise) have the option of logging into the site and enter new products into the system. The users can then log in and view products based on brands and categories.

In the ERD I have created all the tables, fields and one-to-many relations to the best of my knowlegde. I think that went well until the `category` tables.

I want the products to be categorized in like "*MEN&SHOES*", "*KIDS&CLOTHES*". I figured out I am going to need 2 tables for that: `CategoryPersonGroup` & `CategoryProductGroup`. But I do not know what is the right approach to link this to the `products` table. Please help! This is my ERD:

[image]

Comment: It is good to know how to format your questions & responses, and to apply that knowledge. This time I have formatted your question for you, next time put some effort in formatting it yourself, please.

Comment: @Tadeck what do you mean, what did you format?

Comment: Created paragraphs, corrected spelling, inserted image. You have the editing history here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8662273/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `many to 1` relations between product and category tables would be convenient such as:
`Product (N) -- has -- (1) CategoryProductGroup`
`Product (N) -- has -- (1) CategoryPersonGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance approach to this matter, i.e. make category table to store any values that are common to all the articles, and then make separate tables that will inherit category table, in which you can store your own values for that tables. And that's it, just link the main category table to persons and voila.

Comment: Categories ( table) <- inherits Shoes, Clothing ... ( tables)

Comment: Relationship between Person and Categories is 1-N, i.e. one person can have many categories, and between category and person also 1-N.